# Two mains in program

Tags: c, networking, client-server

here is the situation: I need to send a data to a neighbor(socket) and then switch to listening mode. Ive got a client part in `client.c`, which just listens, and server part in `server.c` - sends data. Using sockets I need to have a `main()` in both of them. How should I get them "cooperate" together, so both `mains`s are not going result in error?

Or any other ideas how to solve this issue with sending and listening?

Thanks in advance!

Lucas

Comment: may be you can use Multi Threading

Comment: Responding to your subject line - There can never be two `main()` in a program.

Comment: @Mahesh: there can, you can redefine the entry point to something else

Comment: @Mihai - `main()` is the starting point of execution for any `C, C++` program. What do you mean by "redefining the entry point to something else" ?

Comment: Each of the assembly languages need a label for the entry point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Examples This label can be changed, the linker can be configured to look for something else.

Comment: Also, you can tweak compiler to produce the starting point from a different function, other than `main`. It's just a convention (that is so widely used than no one thinks to change it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create two executables from the sources. Each of them will have its own `main`.

Or, you can create a single executable and let it `fork` another process or create another thread. When creating a new thread you'll specify the second "main" to be the thread function.

When `fork`-ing, you should create two functions `main_server` and `main_client` and let the actual `main` decide which of them to call, just after the `fork`. See snippet:

```
int main_server(int argc, int argv){
  //TODO: complete
  return 0;
}

int main_client(int argc, int argv){
  //TODO: complete
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, int argv){
  //TODO: parse args and get argv_server, argv_client, argc_server, argc_client
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
     //TODO: handle error and leave
  } else if (pid) {
     // start client here for example
     main_client(argc_client, argv_client);
  } else {
     main_server(argc_server, argv_server);
     wait(pid);
  }
  return 0;
  /* TODO: each of the above calls should be checked for errors */
}
```

Hope it helps.

Note: it's better to create a separate executable but if you are required to have only one, use the above snippet.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to keep listening on one port and keep sending on other port? at the same time

Comment: @shaggy: each process has an identifier called PID. When doing a `fork`, the parent process receives the `pid` of the child. I've updated the answer to include the pid and to fix a bug: each time you do a `fork`, you should `wait` for the child to finish before finishing yourself

Comment: could you please have a look at this [link](http://fyels.com/Hma00p) and add a commment or code how should i use that `select`, im quite confused already, not even skilled in `c`. thanks a lot

Comment: hey, could you please help me? or let me at least know

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that these programs will compile into separate binaries that become separate processes.  You will start the "server" program (which will run its main) and then the client program (which will run its main).  They communicate over the socket you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to do this is using "select()" method. This is only for the socket programming in Linux/Unix environment. Using this you can have both sending and listening task done in the same main(). Here's the tutorial for this method.

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#selectman

What it does is that instead of using fork() it puts all the sockets in a read_set. and then it goes into an infinite do-while() loop. Now this is very useful for socket programming in Linux/Unix. What happens in Linus/Unix each socket is assigned a File Descriptor(FD) in which they write the data and then it is transferred. It treats I/O console as a FD. So it puts the console FD in read_set, then all the other listening ports in read_set and then waits for the data from any of the above FD. So if you have data in console it will select that FD and perform the task you've written. Or will be in the listening mode until you close the program.

Now this is better than the fork() one because while using fork(), if didn't handled properly it could create a fork-bomb which would create processes recursively and will bomb your main memory. So its better to create a single process and have both functionality in it.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to keep listening on one port and keep sending on other port? at the same time

Comment: The `fork` solution above has nothing to do with concurrent sending and receiving. It is only a mean to have two "main"s in the same translation unit.

Comment: @Shaggy: For that purpose You will have to create two different threads as 1 thread can do one task at a time.
@Mihai: You are absolutely right. I was just stating a better solution in the Unix environment. That's it.